# Laravel - Custom link register and check Validator

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i have a question: How can i change link register? Example: normal if i run command auth -> i will have route abc.com/register.

But i want to change it to abc.com/register/username with username is member introduce. If register how can i check if this username is exist?

```
class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'username' => 'required|string|max:255|unique:users',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {

        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: you make list of predefined usernames then. seems unusual for me. i would rather let the user register first then redirect to `domain.test/profile/{username}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of calling `Auth::routes()`, register these routes manually and modify them as you need:

```
// Authentication Routes...
$this->get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
$this->post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
$this->post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

// Registration Routes...
$this->get('register/{username}', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
$this->post('register/{username}', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');

// Password Reset Routes...
$this->get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.request');
$this->post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.email');
$this->get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset');
$this->post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
```

To ensure usernames are unique, add `exists:users` to your validator's rule for name (assuming the your users table is named `users`).

```
return Validator::make($data, [
    'name' => 'required|string|max:255|exists:users',
    'username' => 'required|string|max:255|unique:users',
    'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
    'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
]);
```

Comment: Won't work because OP asks for `abc.com/register/username` solution. So he wants username was a part of URI.

Comment: You've just updated the code, but it still won't work because you need to intercept `username` and default `showRegistrationForm ` doesn't do that. It also doesn't do any validation at all.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin He will obviously have to override `showRegistrationForm` and/or `register` functions.

Comment: @Phuc Vo why did you choose this answer? There is no way this answer could help you with your problem.